# Comparing 2D list item with each of the rest in python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to compare my 2D list items. My list looks like this:

```
print(data) 
[['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['2', '4'], ['2', '5'], ['2', '6'], ['3', '4'], ['2', '1'], ['3', '5'], ['4', '6'], ['5', '6']]
```

My point is to find if there is same item 2 times. Not exactly the same but in my case it would be: 
there is *data[0]* which is *['1', '2']* and *data[6]* which is *['2', '1']*. I need to remove "duplicates" like this one. 
Just wondering if there is some function for this.
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the solution of @Abhinav Mathur

But if you want to preserve the list order and format, the solution could be a bit more elaborate

Something like this:

```
data = [['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], 
        ['2', '4'], ['2', '5'], 
        ['2', '6'], ['3', '4'], 
        ['2', '1'], ['3', '5'], 
        ['5', '3'], ['4', '6'], 
        ['5', '6'], ['1', '2'],
        ['5', '3']]


len_data = len(data)
i=0
while i < len_data:
  curr_value = sorted(data[i])
  data[i+1:] = [val for val in data[i+1:] if sorted(val) != curr_value]
  i+=1
  len_data = len(data)

print(data)
```

I modified the list adding more duplicates and different values to demonstrate how it works

result

```
[['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['2', '4'], ['2', '5'], ['2', '6'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '5'], ['4', '6'], ['5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple list comprehension:

```py
data = [list(i) for i in set([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in data])]
print(data)
```